# Await component doesn't send OK

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to do a await message and list for my setWelcome but it does not send me Ok when I select in the Select menu and I do not know if it is good for the after

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#0099ff")
            .setTitle("Configuration du message de bienvenue")
            .setDescription("Veuillez choisir le type de bienvenue !")
    
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('type')
                    .setPlaceholder('Choisir le type de bienvenue')
                    .addOptions([
                        {
                            label: 'image',
                            description: 'Le type de bienvenue sera une image',
                            value: 'image',
                            emoji: '️'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'message',
                            description: 'Le type de bienvenue sera un message',
                            value: 'message',
                            emoji: ''
                        },
                    ]),
            );

        const message = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] })

        const filter = i => {
            return i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
        };
        
        interaction.channel.awaitMessageComponent({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 30000 })
            .then(interaction => interaction.deferReply("Ok"))
            .catch(err => console.log(`No interactions were collected.` + err));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.deferReply()` to reply a content, while `.deferReply()` has only 2 options: **`ephemeral`** and **`fetchReply`**.

```js
interaction.channel.awaitMessageComponent({ 
   filter, 
   componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', 
   time: 30000 
})
.then((i) => i.reply({ content: 'ok' }))
.catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

- `.deferReply()` sends a "Bot is thinking" message, which increases the application command's reply time from 3 seconds to 15 minutes.